# Sqlite3 Python - Check if a field > integer

Tags: python, sqlite

I Have a code to check if he/sheis an admin or not, but how would i check if the number in the database is higher than the required?

The field in the table is named adminlevel

```
def login():
def loggedin():

    if adminlevel > 0:
        print("Hello There Admin!")
        print("Commands: Bet, Deposit, Logout")
        print("Admin Commands: Ban, Give Credits")
    else:
        print("Hello there {}".format(username))
        print("Commands: Bet, Deposit, Logout")

adminlevel = 0
username = input("Please enter your username: ")
password = getpass("Please enter your password: ")
admin = c.execute("select 1 from accounts where adminlevel > 0")
c.execute("select 1 from accounts where username = ? and password = ?", (username, password))
if c.fetchone():
    print('Hello there! {}'.format(username))
    loggedin()
else:

    print("Username and Password Not Found!")
    login()
```

Comment: `... where adminlevel > required_value` or `... where adminlevel > required_value and ...`. What are you trying to do ? Maybe you have to do it in one `SELECT` ? Or maybe you need `SELECT * ...` to get all values in row and later check some value ? It seams you have to learn SQL first.

Comment: say if adminlevel > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    if c.fetchone():
    c.execute("select 1 from accounts where adminlevel > 0")
    if c.fetchone():
        print("Hello There Admin!")
        print("Commands: Bet, Deposit, Logout")
        print("Admin Commands: Ban, Give Credits")
    else:
        loggedin()
```

Just did this, forgot it works the same as my login.

Comment: you could use `*` in `"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?` and then `data = c.fetchone()` and check `data['adminlevel'] > 0` (or something similar). This way you make only one request to database. Maybe in small program it doesn't matter but in bigger we try to do less requests to database.